# How do I minimize the color selector in Visual Studio (Mac)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, storyboard

How do I get out of this jam, where I've opened the color editor in Visual Studio (v7.0.1 build 24) and pressed Maximize? I'm finding the color selector popover to be completely broken, the close button does not work. Also, it will not set the color when I enter a HEX value.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you click on some other property field?

Comment: Try pressing Alt-F4 ?  For bitmaps, Paint.Net works much better.

Comment: Try hitting `Command + W` or the `Escape` key.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, running Visual Studio Community v7.0.1 (build 24) ... ESC doesn't work, Command+W doesn't work ... I did find a solution: open my Storyboards in XCode and edit in a legit piece of software!

Answer (score 0):

Open your Storyboards / XIBs in Xcode and edit there.